# Multiple datepicker using jquery

Tags: jquery, datepicker

One issue I noticed while selecting array of dates in multiple datepicker using jQuery. I picked few dates in November and moved them to December. Once I pick any date in December, calendar automatically switched to November while it should have stayed in December. The same behavior happens if I move to any later month as well.

Below is the code i used:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#arry_dates" ).multiDatesPicker 
        ({ showOn: 'button',
        autoOpen: true,
        minDate: 0,
        buttonImage: 'favicon.ico',
        buttonImageOnly: true, 
    }); 
});
```

Comment: several ways to implement multiple datepickers...  question is useless if we can't replicate using your code

Answer (score 0):

Seeing that you're using $( "#arry_dates" )..., it means you're using an ID for your input such as:

```
<input type="text" id="arry_dates" />

$(function() {
    $( "#arry_dates" ).multiDatesPicker 
        ({ showOn: 'button',
        autoOpen: true,
        minDate: 0,
        buttonImage: 'favicon.ico',
        buttonImageOnly: true, 
    }); 
});
```

Change from ID to class such as:

```
<input type="text" class="arry_dates" />

$(function() {
    $( ".arry_dates" ).multiDatesPicker 
        ({ showOn: 'button',
        autoOpen: true,
        minDate: 0,
        buttonImage: 'favicon.ico',
        buttonImageOnly: true, 
    }); 
});
```

This should then treat them independently.